# Where can I find lots of annotated stock charts to help me improve my chart reading skills?

Tags: trading, technical-analysis

I'm learning to read stock charts. I'd like to be able to look at a ton of charts that have been marked up with the usual support/resistance/trend lines, channels, etc. and annotated with expert analysis predicting the direction of the stock and identifying where a good place would have been to enter the trade, one or more reasonable targets, and a stop to exit the trade.

Even better would be pairs of plain and marked up and annotated charts. I would draw my lines, select entry, targets, and stop, predict the direction and make notes on the plain chart then compare my work to the expert's work on the marked up chart.

Does such a resource exist?

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find trading books a good way to learn about new charting techniques, indicators and patterns. A good trading book will explain the concept thoroughly, give plenty of examples and provide additional resources for further learning.

A good book to get started with is Charting Secrets by Louise Bedford. She has also got a range of other books including Trading Secrets. These books provide charts with no indicators, which you can make a photocopy of and practice drawing the indicators, you can then check with her complete charts over the page.

You can also practice further by printing out charts from your PC and filling in the indicators.

Most good trading books will also show you how you can set up your entries and stops based on different indicators and trading strategies.